# Trouble setting up a ctrl + keydown event listener (Not detected)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have an event listener that console logs a text string after a ctrl  + left/right arrow key is pressed simultaneously. However, the event isn't being picked up by the function below:

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) { 
    if (event.which === 37 && event.ctrlKey) {
    console.log('ctrl-left');
    } 

if (event.which === 39 && event.ctrlKey) {
    console.log('ctrl-right');
    } 

else {
    console.log('nothing detected');
    }
});
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're missing a closing `});`

Comment: With a little cleanup of the code it appears to [work fine](https://jsbin.com/vihekobubu/edit?html,output).

Comment: It's still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your if branches, making a `CTRL+Left` keypress to log both `ctrl-left` and `nothing detected` at the same time.

Also, the browser's default event handling would need to be stopped to avoid issues.

This worked for me on Firefox 44.0.2:

```js
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.which === 37 && event.ctrlKey) {
      console.log('ctrl-left');
    } else if (event.which === 39 && event.ctrlKey) {
      console.log('ctrl-right');
    } else {
      console.log('nothing detected');
    }
});
```

Comment: Some browsers use ctrl+left/right to go back/forward in history, so remember to use `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @KunalOjha What are you expecting to see and what are you seeing instead? How are you testing this? What browser are you using?

Some more details would be needed, as otherwise this should work in normal conditions.

Comment: @EduardMoraru Ok it is working now. But only when I do a ctrl + option keypress with the left/right arrow. I was just testing the ctrl button by itself, didn't know you need the option key included as well